# Make UIPicker have at least one foot value?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, formatting, uipicker

Just like with Apples timer app, you can't select "0". You have to choose at least 1 hour or 1 minute. Here is how I'm formatting the textfield for the picker..

```
//Formats the textfield based on the pickers.
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

NSString *result = [feetArray objectAtIndex:[feetPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]];

result = [result stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ft", [feetArray objectAtIndex:[feetPicker selectedRowInComponent:1]]];
result = [result stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@", [inchArray objectAtIndex:[inchesPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]]];
result = [result stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", [inchArray objectAtIndex:[inchesPicker selectedRowInComponent:1]]];
result = [result stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@in", [fractionArray objectAtIndex:[fractionPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]]];

RiseTextField.text = result;
}
```

What I need to if they choose "0" all the way across, I want the foot to automatically go to 1 on the picker. I have 3 pickers in my view made as one. 2 components for feet, 2 components for inches then 1 component for fractions. so its displayed in the textfield like 10f 09 1/16in.

Comment: Is this like there are two component in your picker one for feet and another for inches? and you don't want to allow 0 feet and 0 inches right?

Comment: Yes, I have 3 pickers in my view made as one. 2 components for feet, 2 components for inches then 1 component for fractions. so its displayed in the textfield like 10f 09 1/16in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially what you want to do is this:(assuming that row 0 contains the zero values)

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if (([feetPicker selectedRowInComponent:0] == 0)&&
        ([feetPicker selectedRowInComponent:1] == 0)&&
        ([inchesPicker selectedRowInComponent:0] == 0)&&
        ([inchesPicker selectedRowInComponent:1] == 0)&&
        ([fractionPicker selectedRowInComponent:0] == 0)){
        // All values zero
        [feetPicker selectRow:1 
                  inComponent:1 
                     animated:YES];
        return;
    }
    // Handle valid value
}
```

On a side note consider using an `NSMutableString` for `result`. Then instead of creating a new `NSString` every line you can just call `[result appendFormat:@"....` to modify the one you have.

Comment: I have 3 pickers in my view made as one. 2 components for feet, 2 components for inches then 1 component for fractions. so its displayed in the textfield like 10f 09 1/16in. That help the code make more sense?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have also said that I didn't want a value less than 1 foot to be allowed. If it's under a foot, the app crashes when calculating.

Comment: So it seems to work like this as needed. if (([feetPicker selectedRowInComponent:0] == 0)){
        // All values zero
        [feetPicker selectRow:1 
                  inComponent:1 
                     animated:YES];
    }

Comment: actually this was this fix: if (([feetPicker selectedRowInComponent:0] == 0 & [feetPicker selectedRowInComponent:1] == 0)){ // All values zero [feetPicker selectRow:1 inComponent:1 animated:YES]; }